# ViewController max width / mask?

Tags: mask, viewcontroller, css

First of all I want to say that I didn't make this myself but I have to edit this code for a friend of mine.

So there is a storyboard with a ViewController called 'PressViewController'. 
In this view there are many images side by side. When I go to 'Utilities' > 'Attributes' the 'Width' of this ViewController is set to '10000'.

In the ViewController I can only see a few images. There are like 20 images and I only can see 15. Although I can't scroll in this ViewController there is a way to add more images to it, but I can't find it.

In the 'PressViewController.m' there is a rectangle drawn.

```
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(19170, 450);
scrollview.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

The rectangle drawn is '19170' width. This is lager than the ViewController.

So my question is. How can I add more images to my ViewController? 
I'll hope someone can help me out. Thanks instead :)

Comment: You need to set content size, scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(IMAGE_WIDTH*20, IMAGE_HEIGHT)// 20 is [images count]

Comment: The images having variable width. But I guess you misunderstood my question. The ViewController isn't lagre enough in my Storyboard. I can't add more images trough (visual) my Storyboard..

Comment: Ok, You can use, view width as IMAGE_WIDTH eg.,(320*20,367)